# Python Pandas histogram not recognizing 'by' grouping argument

Tags: python, arguments, pandas, histogram

I got an error message when trying to produce histograms by grouping. Here is the code and error message.

I have the 0.9.1 Pandas version

```
>>> data.hist(by=np.random.randint(0, 4, 1000))
(most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1671, in hist_series
 ax.hist(values, **kwds)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7868, in hist
 p.update(kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 659, in update
 raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s'%k)
 AttributeError: Unknown property by
```

Comment: Can you show the output of ``pandas.__version__``?

Comment: Not enough information here. Can you please add to it? pandas 0.10 and 0.11 are available, can you try them?